# Is this $f(x)$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to check if the function $f(x)$ is convex, where

$$ f(x)=\bigl|a|x|-x\bigr|^2.$$

There are several possibilities to check if the function is convex:

1. The second derivative: Not possible, because it is only subdifferential.
2. Geometry: too complicated for this case.
3. Convex inequality: $$f(tx+(1-t)y) \leqslant tf(x) + (1-t)f(y).$$

To 3: How to use the inequality? Can somebody help to put the function into the convex inequality?

Comment: Think also about the geometric interpretation: how does $|a|x|-x|$ work?

Comment: Quit the $L_1$ norm from the title, it has nothing to do with the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you don't need the outer abs |.| because of the square. Hence

$$
f(x)=\vert a\vert x\vert-x\vert^2=(a\vert x\vert -x)^2=a^2\vert x\vert^2-2a\vert x\vert x +x^2
$$
Observe that $\vert x\vert^2=x^2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus,
$$
f(x)=a^2 x^2-2a\vert x\vert x +x^2=(a^2+1)x^2-2a\vert x\vert x
$$
Now, we can consider $f$ for $x\geq0$ and $x<0$, i.e.
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
(a^2-2a+1)x^2,&\quad x\geq 0\\
(a^2+2a+1)x^2,&\quad x< 0
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
(a-1)^2x^2,&\quad x\geq 0\\
(a+1)^2x^2,&\quad x< 0
\end{cases}
$$
In both cases you have a parabola for $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{-1,+1\}$ which are opened up. Hence $f$ is convex. Otherwise one part of $f$ is 0, the other part a parabola open up. So, $f$ is again convex.

Comment: You need to check the convexity of $f$ at $x=0$, the parabola argument is not enough. The function $(|x|-1)^2$ is non-convex, but also consists of two parabolas opened up.

Comment: Yeah you're right. You can easily check that $f$ is continuous and differentiable in 0. The function (\vert x\vert-1)^2 is continuous but not differentiable in 0.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ can be written as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} (a-1)^2 x^2 & x\ge0,\\
(-a-1)x^2 & x\le 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The first derivative is given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}2 (a-1)^2 x & x\ge0,\\
2(-a-1)^2x & x\le 0,
\end{cases}
$$
which is a monotonically increasing function, hence $f$ is convex.

Comment: could you explain how to rewrite this function?

Comment: @Peter If $x\geq 0$, $|x|=x$ and therefore $a|x|-x = (a-1)x$. If $x\leq 0$, then $|x|=-x$ and then $a|x|-x = -(a+1)x$.